# Capture WebBrowser Image

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

This code return a white image after saving with saveFileDialog

```
private void salvaUnImmagineToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {                    
                if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    SaveAsBitmap(webBrowser1, saveFileDialog1.FileName);
                }                
            }

            public void SaveAsBitmap(Control control, string fileName)
            {
                //getthe instance of the graphics from the control
                Graphics g = control.CreateGraphics();

                //new bitmap object to save the image
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height);

                //Drawing control to the bitmap
                control.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, control.Width, control.Height));

                bmp.Save(fileName);
                bmp.Dispose();
            }
```

How I can capture a image of web browser?

Answer (score 2):

try this ...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    wb.Height = 100;
    wb.Width = 100;
    wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
  }

  void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);
    wb.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(wb.Location.X, wb.Location.Y, wb.Width, wb.Height));

    this.pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = bmp;
  }

}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: it doesn't work the picturebox is empty and pictureBox1.Image.Save("webbrowserimage.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp); return error

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net)

That's very fine library for parse HTML:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("Yor Path(local,web)"); 
var result=doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img");//return HtmlCollectionNode
```